# Implicit Function Theorem differentiation issues- how is it done?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I saw a written process to solve the following question: For $C^1$ function $f:U(\subset\Bbb{R}^n)\to \Bbb{R}$, such that ${\partial f\over \partial x_i}\ne 0$ for all $1\le i\le n$, find ${\partial x_1\over \partial x_2}{\partial x_2\over \partial x_3}...{\partial x_n\over \partial x_1}$.

The solution legitimately claimed that a set of equations is achieved:

$\begin{cases}
f(x_1(x_2,...,x_n),x_2,...,x_n)=0  \\[2ex]
f(x_1,x_2(x_1,x_3,...,x_n),...,x_n)=0 \\[2ex]
\vdots \\[1ex]
f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n(x_1,...,x_{n-1}))=0 \\[2ex]
\end{cases}$

Where, for instance, $x_1(x_2,...,x_n)$ is a function of $n-1$ variables, locally determining $x_1$ in the original equation, as guaranteed by the theorem.

The next thing done in the solution, is differentiation the $i$th equation by $x_{i+1}$ where $1\le i\le n-1$, and the $n-$th equation by $x_1$. Here's what I didn't understand:

$\begin{cases}
{\partial f\over \partial x_1}{\partial x_1\over \partial x_2}+{\partial f\over \partial x_2}=0  \\[2ex]
{\partial f\over \partial x_2}{\partial x_2\over \partial x_3}+{\partial f\over \partial x_3}=0  \\[2ex]
\vdots \\[1ex]
{\partial f\over \partial x_n}{\partial x_n\over \partial x_1}+{\partial f\over \partial x_n}=0 \\[2ex]
\end{cases}$

How does one arrive at this? Isn't ${\partial f\over \partial x_1}{\partial x_1\over \partial x_2}$ and ${\partial f\over \partial x_2}$ practically the same? Or at least in the same multiplication, and not addition? Can someone put some light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the chain rule: if $f=f(x_1,x_2)$ and $x_1=x_1(x_2)$, then
$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}.
$$
Indeed, $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} dx_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}dx_2$, but $dx_1 = x_1'(x_2)dx_2$.

Please notice that I am carefully avoiding to state precise assumptions and theorems.

Comment: You made it very clear to me. Thank you.